# How to handle multiple clients in a python socket programming

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

I don't have much ideas about how to handle more than 1000 client socket script with a single server socket programming. When I search on web I found that multi threading socket programming, etc. What is the best way to handle larger amount of clients in a socket programming